# change keyboard language in client-side programming languages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to focus in input element change keyboard language.
is there a way to change keyboard language in client-side programming languages ?
is there a way to change keyboard language in javascript ?

Comment: Not sure a browser can have that sort of control over an operating system

Comment: Like Dvorak? You can assume that certain keys are really other keys onkeyup based on `Event.keyCode`.

Answer (score 0):

The browser has no ability to force the operating system to use a different language for the keyboard.

The best you can do is set the language for the page (e.g. `<html lang='fr'>`[using codes from this list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry)) and the OS will change the language if it wants to.

For example, on OSX, there is a setting in `System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources` called `Automatically switch to a document's input source` that will toggle if the user wants the keyboard to switch to the documents language.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a web app on a client like a Browser, Javascript wouldn't have any control over what happens on the OS level. It is just provided a thread in memory to run it's process in. Changing the keyboard language is something that the user will have to initiate. The only thing I can think of that you could do for good user experience is to show a tooltip to the user to change his or her language settings